# p-calendar maxDate and maxDate values are not updating real time

Tags: angular, primeng

p-calendar maxDate and maxDate values are not updating real time

Html

```
    <p-calendar (onSelect)="_loadTimeSlot()" [readonlyInput]="true" [(maxDate)]="maxDateSat" [(minDate)]="minDateSat" class="pc-f-calendar" inputId="timeSlotDate" formControlName="timeSlotDate"
      [dateFormat]="calendarDateFormat" [locale]="calendarLocale" [placeholder]="calendarHolder" appendTo="body" showIcon="true"
      [showOnFocus]="true" [monthNavigator]="true"  [yearNavigator]="true"  yearRange="1970:2100">

    </p-calendar>
```

TS

```
   this.minDateSat = new Date(gs.minDt);
   this.maxDateSat = new Date(gs.maxDt);
   console.log("this.minDateSat >> ",this.minDateSat);
   console.log("this.maxDateSat >> ",this.maxDateSat);
```

In type script able to see the updated values. But the UI cannot see the updated min and max date. Next time call its update using previous values.

Comment: Are the properties @Input?

Comment: Yes All min and max dates are input.Its setting TS correctly. But cannot see in UI. Second time call able to first values.

Comment: what is the component changeDetection?

Answer (score 1):

change this `[(maxDate)]="maxDateSat"` to this `[maxDate]="maxDateSat"`

```js
<p-calendar (onSelect)="_loadTimeSlot()" 
     [readonlyInput]="true" [maxDate]="maxDateSat" [minDate]="minDateSat" 
     class="pc-f-calendar" inputId="timeSlotDate" formControlName="timeSlotDate"
     [dateFormat]="calendarDateFormat" [locale]="calendarLocale" [placeholder]="calendarHolder" appendTo="body" 
     showIcon="true" [showOnFocus]="true" [monthNavigator]="true"  [yearNavigator]="true"  yearRange="1970:2100">
</p-calendar>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-pckv4z)